# CSS: using -*-transform: rotate. alignment problems

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

For my [HTML picture viewer](https://gitorious.org/az-website/website/blobs/master/pics/pics.php), I tried to autorotate some of my pictures via CSS `-*-transform: rotate` (by 90 degree). Because the width was bigger than the height of the pictures, the `img` element was too small and the rotated picture overlaid some of the text above and below.

To fix/workaround this issue, I created a `div` around it with the expected size. This lead to another problem that the image was also misplaced now. To fix/workaround this second issue, I created a second `div` around it which fixed the bad position.

One example (online: [here](http://www.az2000.de/pics/2011_06_17__paris/IMG_1592.JPG?size=0.5)):

- The picture has size w=1024, h=768.
- I am rotating it by 90 degree.
- The outer `div`: `<div style="display:block; width:768px; height:1024px;">`
- The inner `div`: `<div style="position:relative; left:-128px; top:128px; display:block;">`

This results in the correct / expected / wanted positioning and alignment.

I wonder though if there is more elegant / cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing both divs, and setting a margin to your img:

```
margin:128px -128px;
```

It should work, and it's a bit cleaner.

Ps: 128 is (1024-768)/2.